# Where do I create an issue on lab.civicrm?

Tags: civicontribute

I found a small bug in this file:

> /sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.tpl

Where do I submit an issue on lab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues. You might need to create an account if you don't already have an account there or a civicrm.org account. Then you'll see a new issue button. But search there first if it hasn't already been reported.

Comment: ok thanks again Demerit, it wasn't reported so I submitted a new issue.